# Can a facebook app throught api send a message or notice to a facebook page?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps, facebook-page

I have an app and I need to contact facebook pages admins to notice pages admins that we have received a review about their page.
Those pages are automatically added via query to facebook api, but we can't see email address from those queries, so we need to send a notice to the page or at least contact them in some way.

Can you help me?

Comment: I think the most you could do is try and make a post on the page; but whether or not that is possible will depend on the page’s settings.